# how to connect by using selection instead of drag and drop like the example http://jsbin.com/aliniz/243/edit

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
selecting: function (event, ui) {
        // change class and image

      $(this)
            .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
            .find("img")
            .removeAttr("src")
            .attr("src", ico_userChecked);

        $(ui.selected)
            .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
            .find("img")
            .removeAttr("src")
            .attr("src", ico_userChecked);

      svgDrawLine($(this), $(ui.selected));

}
```

i am able to add this but its not connecting  i know that we cant  use ui.selected in selecting func like they used drag in drop func so what should i do please help me thank you in advance

Comment: http://jsbin.com/aliniz/243/edit

Comment: my connection should be made when i select a box on left side and then a box on right side instead of drag and drop